# Open file using exec in shell failed

Tags: bash, file, shell

Need to open some file for read in shell:

```
exec 4<$lock
```

But failed. The error message is:

```
Line 196: exec: 4: not found
```

Is there any insight?

Comment: What is the value of `$lock`?

Comment: As written, if `$lock` is empty, you get an 'ambiguous redirect' error; if it refers to a non-existent file, you get an appropriate 'file not found' error; and if `$lock` is readable, you get success.  The error you got strongly indicates there was a space after the `4` when you tried it. I don't think that tinkering with `IFS` can screw this up. So, in the absence of a complete, reproducible script (and some discussion of what you've tried to avoid the problem), I would classify this as 'operator error'.  It happens to all of us on occasion.

Comment: lock is a file with read permission set. And I guarantee you that no space exists between 4 and <.  It should be another problem causing this. Any other insights?

Answer (score 2):

That looks like `exec` is trying to run a program called `4`.

I can reproduce that error message by putting a space between `4` and `<somefilename`, as in:

```
$ ( exec 4 <somefilename )
bash: exec: 4: not found
```

See if your script has a misplaced space.

Comment: I have fixed this problem by generating a cmd first and eval it. So I think this is a expansion problem. Still no idea on the exact cause.